# Elasticsearch running but not responding to certain APIs

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch is running and I can verify that by

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200'
```

which gives me a response like

```
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Bethany Cabe",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.4.2",
    "build_hash" : "927caff6f05403e936c20bf4529f144f0c89fd8c",
    "build_timestamp" : "2014-12-16T14:11:12Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.2"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

All this is fine but when I do

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/health?v'
```

there's no response. curl simply gets stuck until I have to close it forcibly. I have also checked with other API testing tools like RESTClient for Firefox.

The weird thing is that elasticsearch responds to some methods but not to others.
Can you help me with it?